# Create dictionary from difference of two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose, if I have a dictonary,

```
dictA = {
         'flower': 
                 {
                  'jasmine': 10,
                  'roses': 
                        {
                         'red': 1,
                         'white': 2
                        }
                 },
        'fruit':
               {
                'apple':3
               }
        }
```

and if `dictA` is updated (say to `dictB`)

```
dictB = {
         'flower': 
                 {
                  'jasmine': 10,
                  'roses': 
                         {
                          'red': 1,
                          'white': 2
                         }
                 },
         'fruit':
                 {
                  'apple':3,
                  'orange': 4
                 }
        }
```

now how would I get a dictionary of only newly added items (preserving the structure}, something like,

```
difference(dictB, dictA) = {'fruit': {'orange': 4}}
```

by this way, I would avoid storing redundant items each time and instead have a smaller dictionary showing only newly added items

*This kind of manipulation of dictionaries has a lot of practical uses, but unfortunately harder*

Any help would be much appreciated and Thanks in advance

Comment: does you need difference of items in depth too? let's say that "roses" have difference

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: you can use [dictdiffer](https://pypi.org/project/dictdiffer/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DictDiffer`:

```
from dictdiffer import diff, patch, swap, revert

dictA = {
         'flower':
                 {
                  'jasmine': 10,
                  'roses':
                        {
                         'red': 1,
                         'white': 2
                        }
                 },
        'fruit':
               {
                'apple':3
               }
        }

dictB = {
         'flower':
                 {
                  'jasmine': 10,
                  'roses':
                         {
                          'red': 1,
                          'white': 2
                         }
                 },
         'fruit':
                 {
                  'apple':3,
                  'orange': 4
                 }
        }

result = diff(dictA, dictB)

# [('add', 'fruit', [('orange', 4)])]
print(f'Diffrence :\n{list(result)}')

patched = patch(result, dictA)

# {'flower': {'jasmine': 10, 'roses': {'red': 1, 'white': 2}}, 'fruit': {'apple': 3}}
print(f'Apply diffrence :\n{patched}')
```